# How can I create a subquery in mysql?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table like this one:

```
|col1         |id  |
--------------------
|_22_1_565_18_|1   |
|_22_1_18_    |2   |
|_77_18_      |3   |
|_22_1_55_45  |4   |
|_18_1_65_13_ |5   |
|_782_8_      |6   |
|_782_1_8_21_ |7   |
|_72_1_8_21_  |8   |
|_782_8_251_  |9   |
|_22_4_1_     |10  |
|_77_1_5_21_  |11  |
|_5_6_7_      |12  |
```

col1 contains always numbers separated by the "_" character (one after, one before as you see). I need to write a query:

1) To choose all the rows that contains the string "*18*" (in this case row 1, 2, 3, 5)

2) To find out what string sequences are the 2 most common in the "*18*" choosen rows (in this case the "*22*" and "*1*" strings)

3) To choose all the rows not containing the string "*18*" but containing the common strings "*22*" and "*1*" (in this case the rows 4, 10)

4) To add to the chosen rows the ones nears them in terms of id proximity, in particular the 2 rows after and the 2 rows before each of them, always excluding the ones containing "*18*" (in this case the rows 6, 8, 9, 11, 12)

The final result of the query, in this case, are the rows 4, 10, 6, 8, 9 11, 12.

I know it's hard but, how can I do?

Comment: If you have sql script then share it we will make queries  to test this

Comment: first store the data in `comma separated` form. not using `_` and what you have tried? we are not here to do your homework

Comment: for the 1st query: `select * from table1
where find_in_set('18',replace(col1,'_',','))>0`

Comment: I don't know how to do this, I've tryed with VB .NET and different/separated query with for loops but it's very slow performing, I am not an expert in mysql

Comment: You should normalize your data.

Comment: This is not a problem and then?

Comment: If you Normalize you database design then it will be easy to query data with performance.

Comment: I want to do this in mysql but I don't know how, I've tryed with VB .NET instead using only mysql with a big loss of performance

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
select * from table 
where col1 like '%_18_%'
```

---

2)

```
select * from table
where col1 like '%_22_%' and col1 like '%_1_%'
```

---

3)

```
select * from table 
where col1 not like '%_18_%' 
and (col1 like '%_22_%' and col1 like '%_1_%')
```

---

4)

```
select * from table 
where col1 not like '%_18_%' 
or (col1 not like '%_22_%' and col1 not like '%_1_%')
```